# How to connect multiple > 10 wireless sensors to Arduino

Tags: ipad, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot

I am working on a small learning project with arduino in which there are multiple sensors like motors, 7 segment display, temprature sensor, lcd display, button etc and all of these need to talk single IPhone or Ipad.

My first thought is to buy multiple flora arduino having each a sensor. Then each independent unit can connect via bluetooth. But i am not sure if it is good idea or not. How will they all connect to single device.

Idea is like 10 arduino device sending and receiving signal from one iphone or Ipad.

Comment: I don't think you should do a complex project like this if you don't know that motors, buttons and displays are no sensors... there is also no such thing as a wireless sensor, wireless motor, wireless display or wireless button. maybe you should work on your fundamentals first. you will have a pretty hard time otherwise. and even if you have a module that contains a sensor and can communicate to Arduino via Bluetooth, what do you need the Arduino for? Your Ipad already has bluetooth.

Comment: A motor isn't a sensor.  Nor is a LCD display, seven-segment display, or a button.  What you describe is not a small learning project, and it's too broad a project to answer here.

Comment: Hi Piglet/TomServo, i have all these components i have made them work separately with Adruino. Now as next step i want to connect all these component wirelessly with Ipad so i questioned if it is possible. I do understand motor etc is not senor. It was mistake from my side to mention them as sensor. As an example 5 temperature sensors placed in  5 rooms but reporting to one device, which can send and receive instruction.

Answer (score 1):

As Piglet and TomServo said, The motors, 7 segment display, temprature sensor, lcd display, button are not sensors those can be considered as peripherals!

Now even though its a vast topic and you will need a lot of work to accomplish this, Its not hard if you have embedded c or C programming experience.

You should look into how micro controllers work and how to start programming them arduino site should be good starting point!
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/HomePage
https://www.quora.com/Which-are-the-Best-books-on-learning-to-program-microcontroller

Now once you set up your environment and programmed a simple program like toggling a LED, you should start looking at communication protocols,

The devices/peripherals communicate to master/Host microcontroller(Arduino) through set of protocols such as SPI, UART,I2C etc. you will need to decide an ICs for example HDSP-5503 is a seven segment display you can find more at
http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Broadcom-Avago/HDSP-5503/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsx4%2fFVpd5sGZOLZP3%252bEaxq

You can not just buy arduino with ton of sensors and connect it to iPhone, iPhone will require your custom app to support your board check out this guy!
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hm10-bluetooth-serial-lite/id1030454675?mt=8

hopefully this will help good luck!

Comment: Hi Nikhil, i have worked with these components separately and they are all working with Adruino. Now as next part of learning is to connect multiple adruino with single ipad so i questioned is it possible? Which unfortunately no one answered.

Comment: Well yes, your phone /iPad has Bluetooth dual mode which can connect more than one communication devices. ( it cannot connect to more than one audio stream devices)

Comment: Is i worth investigating on radio or wifi. So iPad connected to wifi and all 5 adruino can also connect to wifi. Not sure if it will drain battery quickly?

Comment: Okay no both will consume comparatively equal amount of battery considering you are just sending few commands! What is the issue ?

Comment: Nikhil which WIFI with FLORA Adruino should i use that will go for days with battery power.

Comment: this is a vague question! Well battery consumption depends on the code.  sleep mode power consumption and active mode power consumption and battery capacity! consider https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-battery-life